# Receiving a php loading error after reinstalling WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just did a reinstall of WordPress and am receiving the following error:

**Warning: require_once(/home/www/lifeskandy.com/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/lifeskandy.com/wp-load.php on line 49
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/www/lifeskandy.com/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7.3/lib/php') in /home/www/lifeskandy.com/wp-load.php on line 49**

Here is the code from that section of the wp-load.php file

```
define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/load.php';

// Standardize $_SERVER variables across setups.
wp_fix_server_vars();

require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php';

$path = wp_guess_url() . '/wp-admin/setup-config.php';
```

I've been playing around with things and can't seem to get this resolved; I keep making new errors. I'm sure it's something simple. Can anyone tell me how exactly I need to update this code? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it is the code.. have you checked directory `wp-includes` for the right permission/chmod setings?

Comment: Wordpress is not correctly installed. According to the [full source](https://build.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-load.php#L34), it's entering that branch because `wp-config.php` was not found, but it cannot load all required files under `wp-includes` either.